# Setting neighbor fragment color via GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I need to setup a GLSL fragment shader to change the color of a fragment other than the one currently being processed. Since that may not seem desirable, I'll provide a very brief context.

The project utilizes a render pass whereby a given model is drawn into an FBO with unique colors that correspond to UV coordinates in the texture map. These colors are then sampled and converted to image coordinates so that the texture map for the model can be updated based on what's visible to the camera. Essentially:

```
Render model to FBO
For each FBO pixel
   1. sample secondary texture based on FBO pixel position
   2. convert color at current pixel to image coordinate for the model's texture map
   3. update model's texture with sampled secondary texture at calculated coordinate
End loop
```

The problem is that the current implementation is very CPU bound, so I'm reading the pixels out of the FBO and then manipulating them. Ideally, since I already have the color of the fragment to work with in the fragment shader, I want to just tack on the last few steps to the process and keep everything on the GPU.

The specific issue I'm having is that I don't quite know how (or if it's even possible) to have a fragment shader set the color of a fragment that it is not processing. If I can't work something up by using an extra large FBO and just offsetting the fragment that I want to set the color on, can I work something up that writes directly into a texture?

Any help/advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need a scatter operation (uniform FBO pixel space -> random mesh UV texture destination) to be performed in OpenGL. There is a way to do this, not as simple as you may expect, and not even as fast, but I can't find a better one:

- Run a draw call of type `GL_POINTS` and size equal to the width*height of your source FBO.
- Select model texture as a destination FBO color layer, with no depth layer attached
- In a vertex shader, compute the original screen coordinate by using `gl_VertexID`.
- Sample from the source FBO texture to get color and target position (assuming your original FBO surface was a texture). Assign a proper `gl_Position` and pass the target color to the fragment shader.
- In a fragment shader, just copy the color to the output.

This will make GPU to go through each of your original FBO pixels and scatter the computed colors over the destination texture.

Comment: Hmmm.. this is a very interesting idea. Tommy's approach is more in line with what I already have implemented so I think I'll give that a shot first. I may also give this a try too, though.

Comment: @Xenethyl. I may not have understood your task completely, but from what I see - the scatter can not be implemented in a way @Tommy described. So if you think his idea fits your needs, go on with it, of course, because it's much simpler then mine.

Comment: After thinking about this after dinner tonight I'm starting to realize how doing a ping pong pass doesn't really solve my problem. I don't know whether your solution will work for my current setup, but I do think it's more correct than what Tommy was discussing. For now I've marked this as accepted. Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding.

Comment: @Xenethyl. Thank you. Don't hesitate to ask about any details. I've implemented a lot of similar schemes in GL-3.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to have a fragment shader write to anywhere other than the fragment it is processing. What you probably want to do is ping pong rendering.

In your code, you'd have three textures, matching your listed tasks:

1. the secondary texture
2. the source model texture map
3. the destination model texture map

At a first run, you'd use (1) and (2) as source textures, to draw to (3). Next time through the loop you'd use (1) and (3) to write to (2). Then you'd switch back to using (1) and (2) to write to (3). And so on.

So (2) and (3) are connected with framebuffer objects with the textures supplied as the colour buffer in place of a renderbuffer.

NVidia authored the [GL_NV_texture_barrier extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/texture_barrier.txt) in 2009 that allows you to compact (2) and (3) into a single texture, provided you are explicit about the dividing line between where you're reading and where you're writing. I don't have the expertise to say how widely available it is.

Attempting to read and write to the same texture (as is possible with FBOs) otherwise produces undefined results in OpenGL. Prompting issues at the hardware level are related to caching and multisampling.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your explanation. I just ran through this in my head and I think I see how it can work for me.

Comment: Sorry for revoking my acceptance of this, but I think kvark is correct in that doing a ping pong pass won't actually let me write to arbitrary locations... unless I'm missing something?

Comment: No, quite right. I'd taken the request to be something it isn't; hopefully I helped in some way nevertheless.